# array_combine creating hinky array

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a small scraper using codeigniter that grabs some info from another site using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser library.  I first build two arrays - the first is used as a key and the other array is used as the value.

It all seems to work fine until I try to pull out values using the keys.

Here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [price] => $1,020,000
    [city] => CHICAGO
    [zip] => 60622
    [state] => ILL
    [mls] => 08207131
    [type] => Apartment
    [square_ft] =>  
    [year_built] => U
    [beds] => 4
    [baths] => 2
    [subdivision] =>  
    [area] => CHI - West Town
    [township] => NORTH CHICAGO
)
```

If I try to access the array like this:

```
echo $info['price']."</br>";
```

I get an "Undefined index: price" error.

If I try to access the info like this:

```
echo $info->price;
```

I get an "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

*NOTE*
One thing I noticed when using print_r() on the offending array is that the keys appear as **bold text** where as when I build a test array the keys appear as normal text.  My question is does the bold text signify anything like the keys should be formatted in a special way or something?

Comment: I suspect the bold output means that the keys contain HTML tags, i.e. it's actually something like `$info['<b>price</b>']`. You need to remove the tags when you're processing the DOM from the other site.

Comment: @Barmar - BLAMMO! yessir what you suspected was spot on! strip_tags() did the job! You should have responded in an answer, but thanks! **PROBLEM SOLVED**

Comment: Couldn't post an answer because you never posted the relevant code that needs fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

– Barmar answered the question as follows:

I suspect the bold output means that the keys contain HTML tags, i.e. it's actually something like $info['**price**']. You need to remove the tags when you're processing the DOM from the other site.

Comment: BLAMMO! yessir what you suspected was spot on! strip_tags() did the job! You should have responded in an answer, but thanks! PROBLEM SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $info['price']."</br>";  // for array

echo $info->price;  // for object

$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);

echo $c['green'];  // output 'avocado'
```

example http://codepad.viper-7.com/BkT5U8